# Which is the correct way of cufft plan configuration in case of 3d fft's?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

Lets say I have a 3 dimensional(x=256+2,y=256,z=128) array and I want to compute the FFT (forward and inverse) using cuFFT. And I have a fftw compatible data layout lets say the padding is in the x direction as shown in the size above(+2). How my plan should be ?

```
//forward 
cufftPlan3d(&plan, z, y, x, CUFFT_R2C) 

//or
cufftPlan3d(&plan, x, y, z, CUFFT_R2C)
```

and for inverse ?

```
//Inverse 
cufftPlan3d(&plan, x, y, z, CUFFT_C2R) 

//or
cufftPlan3d(&plan, z, y, x, CUFFT_C2R)
```

If the data is stored in **column major** order how is that going to affect the **plan creation** ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `cufftPlan3d`, the right way to do it would be to use

`cufftplan3d(&plan, x, y, z, type);`

Here `x` means the first dimension, `y` means the second and `z` means the third. 
In your case, you can use them as is without any issue.

All parameters are the same for both forward and inverse, except `type` which changes from `CUFFT_R2C` to `CUFFT_C2R`.

If you are going to use `cufftplanMany`, you will need to do something like this.

```
int dims[] = {z, y, x}; // reversed order
cufftPlanMany(&plan, 3, dims, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, 1, 0, type, batch);
```

`cufftPlanMany` is useful if you are doing batched operations, or if you working with non contiguous data.

Comment: I think what you answered holds good for row major order. what about column major order ? Does it change or not ?

Comment: @SagarMasuti For FFT you should not be thinking in terms of column majorness or row majorness. What matters is the dimension along which you are doing the FFT. If the single dimensional FFT is being performed along your leading dimension (in your case the column), the same logic holds.